# How do you get multiple error handlers in PHP?

Tags: php, function, handler

I tried this:

```
    set_error_handler('ReportError', E_NOTICE | E_USER_NOTICE);
    set_error_handler('ErrorHandler', E_ALL & ~(E_NOTICE | E_USER_NOTICE));
```

But only the second one works. How do I have different error handlers for different types of errors?

Answer (score 6):

Why not have one error handler and filter by error type in the handler and call different functions from there? Make a `GenericErrorHandler()` and do this in it:

```
switch($errno){
   case E_USER_ERROR: UserErrorHandler(...); break;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

So, to latch on to what Westie is saying, the important part is you can only have one error handler, and the set_error_handler() function returns the previously defined error handler, or null if none were defined. So in your error handlers, possibly use a class that stores the previous error handler when registering it, so that when you handle errors with your class method, call the previous error handler as well. An excerpt from the raven-php Sentry client:

```
    public function registerErrorHandler($call_existing_error_handler = true, $error_types = -1)
{
    $this->error_types = $error_types;
    $this->old_error_handler = set_error_handler(array($this, 'handleError'), error_reporting());
    $this->call_existing_error_handler = $call_existing_error_handler;
}
```

and then the handle error method:

```
    public function handleError($code, $message, $file = '', $line = 0, $context=array())
{
    if ($this->error_types & $code & error_reporting()) {
      $e = new ErrorException($message, 0, $code, $file, $line);
      $this->handleException($e, true, $context);
    }

    if ($this->call_existing_error_handler && $this->old_error_handler) {
        call_user_func($this->old_error_handler, $code, $message, $file, $line, $context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have one error handler and handle the errors like this (okay, it's PHP 5.3 but excuse me - slight modifications and it'll work normally)

```
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    switch($errno)
    {
        case E_ERROR:
        {
            # Bla bla bla, your code here
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
});
```

If you really must use two different set_error_handler, then you can use the function call to get the previous error handler. And even then, you'll lose what errors you're filtering for.

Having a controller like that though is much more elegant.

Comment: Please note that this assumes >= PHP 5.4